# Get values from 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

Maybe the header is wrong but i dont know how to explain.
I have 4 csv files with aprox 15000 rows in each looking like this

number,"surname","forename","emailAddress","taxIdentifier"
100238963,"Smith","John","john.smith@gmail.com","xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Im reading in 9999 of the rows and creating a json file we use on a site to check every person, we then get a respond back for most of the users, and that respons is "number"
Then i need to find all them persons in the first array.
I have done it like this today, but it take to much time to check every person like this, is there any better way of doing this?

This is the code for getting the persons from the file and create json file:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Folders\\*" -Include *.csv -Force

foreach ($File in $Files){
    $fname = $file
    $fname = (Split-Path $File.name -leaf).ToString().Replace(".csv", "")
    $Savefile = $fname+ "_Cleaned.csv"

        $users = Import-Csv $File
        $body = "{`"requestId`": `"144x25`",`"items`": ["
 
$batchSize = 9999
$batchNum = 0
$row = 0
while ($row -lt $users.Count) {
    $test = $users[$row..($row + $batchSize - 1)]

foreach ($user in $test) {

    $nr = $user.number
    $tax = $user.taxIdentifier
    $body += "{`"itemId`": `"$nr`",`"subjectId`": `"$tax`"},"
}
```

And then this is the code to deal with the respons:

```
       $Result = @()

foreach ($1 in $response.allowedItemIds)
{
    foreach ($2 in $Users){

        If ($2.number -like $1)
        {
            $Result += [pscustomobject]@{
            number = $2.number
            Surname = $2.surname
            Forename = $2.forename
            Email = $2.emailaddress
            Taxidendifier = $2.taxIdentifier

        }
    }

}

}
$Result | Export-Csv -path "$folders\$savefile" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    $row += $batchSize
    $batchNum++
```

Hope someone has any ideas

Cheers

Comment: Can you give an example of the json request and response for your sample data?

Comment: Body Variable:

{"itemId": "100164211","subjectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"}

Response Variable:

requestId responseId                           allowedItemIds                                 --------- ----------                           --------------                                 144x25    2efb8b47-d693-46ac-96b1-a31288567cf3 {100164211, 100415116, 100738809, 100097320...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just do this:

```
# read the original data file
$originalCsv = @"
number,"surname","forename","emailAddress","taxIdentifier"
1000,"Smith","Mel","mel.smith@example.org","xxxxxxxxxxxx"
3000,"Wilde","Kim","kim.wilde@example.org","xxxxxxxxxxxx"
2000,"Jones","Gryff Rhys","gryff.jones@example.org","xxxxxxxxxxxx"
"@
$originalData = $originalCsv | ConvertFrom-Csv

# get a response from the api
$responseJson = @"
{
  "requestId":      "144x25",
  "responseId":     "2efb8b47-d693-46ac-96b1-a31288567cf3",
  "allowedItemIds": [ 1000, 2000 ]
}
"@
$responseData = $responseJson | ConvertFrom-Json

# filter original data for matches to the response
$matches = $originalData | where-object { $_.number -in $responseData.allowedItemIds }
# number surname forename   emailAddress            taxIdentifier
# ------ ------- --------   ------------            -------------
# 1000   Smith   Mel        mel.smith@example.org   xxxxxxxxxxxx
# 2000   Jones   Gryff Rhys gryff.jones@example.org xxxxxxxxxxxx

# write the data out
$matches | Export-Csv -Path ".\myfile.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I don't know if that will perform better than your example, but it *should* do as it's not got a nested loop that runs `original row count * response row count` times.